# React Native dynamically filled Value of InputText returns empty on form Submit

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native mobile app, I have a profile page with few Input Text fields. I am setting the field values to the current value in the DataBase. All the fields populate with the latest values as required.

The problem is on submitting the form the data returns empty values of the form fields which are dynamically populated. If the form Field  is empty and the user manually enters a value. That value is returns on submission.

The Code is below  **(Updated with a shorter code )**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { Formik } from "formik";


  
export default function App() {
  
  const [theEmail, setTheEmail] = useState()
  const [theFlag, setTheFlag] = useState(true)    
  
  if(theFlag)
  {
      setTheFlag(false)
      setTheEmail("test@test.com")
      
  }


  return (
      <SafeAreaView>
              <Formik
                  initialValues={{ email: '' }}
                  onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
              >
                  {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                      <View>
                          <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                          value={theEmail}
                          onChangeText = {(text)=>setTheEmail(text)}
                          />
                          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
                      </View>
                  )}
      </Formik>


      </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput : {
      borderColor : "red",
      borderWidth : 1,
      margin : 20,
      height : 50,
  }
})
```

Appreciate the help to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you also show us the "../components/forms.js"

Comment: added the forms.js and formFields.js as well

Comment: This is so abstract, cant seem to figure out the problem from the snippet above.

Comment: It's a working code, try running it and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solutions to the problem. Hope it helps someone else with this issue.

Instead of passing the value from database to the `value` property of the `TextInput` and setting the `onChangeText` to the state variable, I passed the state variable to `initialValues` of `<Formik>` ( and in my original file which got the values from the database through an async function, I conditionally rendered the form to avoid the state variable passing the value to `initialValues` before the state is set.)

The resolved code

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { Formik } from "formik";


    
export default function App() {
    
    const [theEmail, setTheEmail] = useState()
    const [theFlag, setTheFlag] = useState(true)   
    const [theRender, setTheRender] = useState(false) 
    
    if(theFlag)  // << ====  if(response.ok && theFlag)  // in original file check for response.ok to get data from database
    {
        setTheFlag(false)
        setTheEmail("test@test.com")
        setTheRender(true) //<< set the state value to true to confirm value passed from async 
    }


    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
               
               {theRender &&  // conditionally rendering the form 

                <Formik
                    initialValues={{ email: theEmail }} // theEmail value is passed 
                    onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
                >
                    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                        <View>
                            <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                            
                            />
                            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
                        </View>
                    )}
        </Formik>
               }


        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput : {
        borderColor : "red",
        borderWidth : 1,
        margin : 20,
        height : 50,
    }
})
```

Now the field is prepopulated with the data from the database and is editable and it submits the default value prefilled or the updated text content.